# Closing SQLiteConnection (SQLiteConnectionWithLock)

Tags: c#, sqlite, portable-class-library, sqlite-net

I'm using [SQLite.NET PCL library](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) in my application.

**What is the best practice to manage connection lifecycle using the library?**

I can't find any examples where SQLiteConnection.Close() method is used. But the common .NET practice is to close connection after each request or bulk of requests. So should I create a single connection for an application and never dispose it?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I wrap my db actions into a `using` statement which will dispose of the `SqlConnection` for me.

```
using (var conn = SqlConnection())
{
    //SQL stuff here
}
```

This will make the `Close()` call after the last `}`, [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) implements that way:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    Close();
}
```

Comment: That answer is specific to ADO.NET Connections & doesn't apply to the speciifc question. How does this apply specifically to SQLite.NET PCL library? It is my understanding when you create a SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection that you have to call its CreateTable method with all the tables classes for that database. This is a lot of overhead every time you create a connection to use a using statement  due to the CreateTable requirement. I am not sure if that would be "Best Practice" for the SQLite.NET PCL library the question was about and the specific class SQLiteConnection referenced in it.

Comment: @RodneyFoley nice comment. Would you provide an answer with approach you use for SQLite.NET PCL?

Comment: @alexey The point of the question was that I didn't have a good approach and none were documented at the time. I have moved away from using SQLite.NET PCL because of a number of issues.  Since it is supposed to be a micro-orm of sorts it seems to have avoided the concept of the IDisposable pattern in general and you have to "trust" that they are disposing of the connection correctly and timely.